# What is a Sacred Word?

Tags: word

Like is a sacred word, but Cart is not.
Eat is a sacred word, but Or is not.
Table is a sacred word, but Ukulele is not.
Technique is a sacred word, but Nuzzled is not.
Everyone is a sacred word, but Token is not.
Rap is a sacred word, but Si is not.

What is a Sacred Word?

Bonus: Can you solve the hidden riddle?

QuatumTwinkie's answer is the first step of the hidden riddle

Hint 1:

> Look at the physical word, not its meaning.

Hint 2:

> Some words could change depending on capitalization, and cursive, but not font (Unless it is wacky)

Hint 3:

> You need to count

Hint 4:

> Counter is a sacred word

Hint 5:

> Hole is a sacred word

Comment: What's Si here?

Comment: Did you "si" the hint? Hahahahahah

Comment: Hahahahahahahah.

Comment: Based on hint 2, could it also (rot13) punatr onfrq ba sbag?

Comment: @DqwertyC Ab, (Hayrff vg vf fbzr penml sbag) ohg vg pbhyq or punatrq ol phefvir

Comment: As per my answer below, could you clarify in your hints which hint applies to which riddle in this puzzle?

Comment: Ok. Quantum Twinkies answer is for the bonus hint

Comment: *Bonus Riddle   .

Comment: Just how close am I getting?

Comment: Very close, you are right with counting something with the physical word. Just don't count stroke counts, try something else

Comment: Are you sure the 3rd row is correct? I thought I figured out the bonus riddle but this one row is throwing me off.

Comment: @obi, you are right, sorry, my mistake

Comment: I find no obvious correlations in summing glyph connected components, minimum glyph strokes, glyph holes, glyph intersections, glyph intersection parity, or pairs or triples of these.¶ Can we get the sacredness of "On", "Ok", "Ow", "is", "Is"?

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that

> The first letters of the *sacred* words spell **LETTER**, and the non-*sacred* word spell **COUNTS**.

Comment: You still didn't answer any of the questions, though

Comment: I am guessing that this is the hidden riddle.

Comment: That is a clue to the hidden riddle

Answer (score 3):

A sacred word is a word where,

> The letters added up via their ascii code value, and then added separately would contain a two. I found two exceptions to this, however.

Like is a sacred word, but Cart is not.

> Like has a value of 389, which when added = 20. Cart has a value of 394 = 16.

Eat is a sacred word, but Or is not.

> Eat has a value of 282 = 12. Or has a value of 193 = 13.

Table is a sacred word, but Ultimate is not.

> Table has a value of 488 = 20. Ultimate has a value of 837 = 18.

Technique is a sacred word, but Nuzzled is not.

> This one is a contradiction to this theory. Technique has a value of 934 = 16. Ultimate has a value of 748 = 19.

Everyone is a sacred word, but Token is not.

> Everyone has a value of 845 = 19, which is another contradiction. Token has a value of 513 = 9.

Rap is a sacred word, but Si is not.

> Rap has a value of 291 = 12. Si has a value of 188 = 17.

This is literally the only connection I could find for this and as QuantumTwinkie found out, it spells out

> LETTER COUNTS

Comment: Nice work, but this is not close. (Read the hints)

Comment: @PotatoLatte, I did read the hints. This changes based on capitalization and required me to count.

Comment: Ah. The "Letter Counts" is for the hidden riddle.

Answer (score 2):

2nd Attempt: I found it (I think)!

> Sacred words are words that require even number of strokes to create
> Like requires 8 strokes, whereas Cart requires 7.
> Eat requires 8 strokes, where Or requires 3.
> Table requires 8 strokes, where Ultimate requires 13.
> Technique requires 14 strokes, where Nuzzled requires 15.
> Everyone requires 14 strokes, where Token requires 9.
> Finally, Rap requires 6 strokes, and Si requires 3.
> On the hints, this is why it's important to look at capitalization and cursive letters, because this changes based on it. On the last hint, Counter requires 10 strokes.

Comment: Close, but it doesn't change based on cursive. Think about the Big Hint. If it were this, I would count the letter "e" as 2 strokes

Comment: @PotatoLatte, really? I write it with one... :|

Comment: But do you write L with 2 and a with 3? (And So On)

Comment: @PotatoLatte, Good point.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the bonus riddle

Thanks to @QuantumTwinkie, we know that

> The first letters of the sacred words spell LETTER, and the non-sacred word spell COUNTS.

So

> By adding the number of letters in each row for the sacred and non-sacred word and using A1Z26, we get 'HELPME'

Comment: This is the bonus riddle, congrats! (I'm sort of more looking for the main riddle, but... :P)

Comment: @PotatoLatte of course. Will this help solve the main riddle in any way or are they completely unrelated?

Comment: Completely unrelated, I just decided to do something for fun because who doesn't like multiple riddles in one?